# Do functions need to be declared anywhere else besides in the class and before the program?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I've been trying to convince myself that that objects of the same type have access to each others private data members. I wrote some code that I thought would help me better understand what is going on, but now I am getting an error from XCODE7 (just 1), that says that I am using the undeclared identifier "combination."

If someone could help me understand where I have gone awry with my code, I would love to learn.

My code should simply print false, if running correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Shared {
public:
    bool combination(Shared& a, Shared& b);
private:
    int useless{ 0 };
    int limitless{ 1 };
};

bool Shared::combination(Shared& a,Shared& b){
    return (a.useless > b.limitless);
}

int main() {

    Shared sharedObj1;
    Shared sharedObj2;

    cout << combination(sharedObj1, sharedObj2) << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combination` is a member function of the class `Shared`. Therefore, it can only be called on an instance of `Shared`. When you are calling `combination`, you are not specifying which object you are calling it one:

```
cout <<    combination(sharedObj1, sharedObj2) << endl;
        ^^^
       Instance?
```

The compiler complains because it thinks you want to call a function called `combination`, but there is none.

So, you'll have to specify an instance:

```
cout << sharedObj1.combination(sharedObj1, sharedObj2) << endl;
```

In this case however, it doesn't matter on which instance it is being called on, so you should make `combination` static, so you can do

```
cout << Shared::combination(sharedObj1, sharedObj2) << endl;
```

Comment: Super answer. Thanks for that tip at the end. Great explanation all around.